# Why is the date command throwing an error despite successfully computing an answer?

Tags: bash, date, mingw-w64

For context I am working on a Windows machine with MINGW64. I have not had the chance to test this on a machine running Linux.

I am working with `[date][1]` in bash and trying to add days to a date represented as seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00, i.e. in format `%s`. I have the following Bash code:

```
DATE1=$(date --date=now "+%s")
echo "DATE1: ${DATE1}"
DATE2=$(date --date="$(date --date="${DATE1}" "+%s")+2 days" "+%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S")
echo "DATE2: ${DATE2}"
```

Which gives console output

```
DATE1: 156133763
date: invalid date '1561337963'
DATE2: 26Jun2019 10:59:24
```

In fact, `DATE2` has the expected value down to the second. However the console still throws an error. Why might this error be occurring? Would it have something to do with running MINGW64?

**An update:**

I ran this on a Debian server I have access to. It computed the time with `now` like on MINGW, but returned a different error: `./test.sh: line 3: --date=1561342165: command not found`.
Running this on the same server with a custom date:

```
DATE1=$(date --date="$(date --date="19Jun2019 11:35:46" "+%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S")" "+%s")
```

Likewise returns

```
DATE1: 1560908146
date: invalid date ‘1560908146’
DATE2: 26Jun2019 12:20:08
```

Which actually indicates it isn't adding to the defined date at all, rather it is just adding to today's date (it's the 24th of June where I am now). Clearly, something is quite wrong!

Comment: Does it work for arbitrary `DATE1`'s, or does it only work when `DATE1` is now?

Comment: Maybe it's my poor bash knowledge, but I can't get it to work even with `DATE1=$(date --date="$(date --date="26Jun2019 11:35:46" "+%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S")" "+%s")`. It returns `date invalid date '1561512946'` and completely misses the addition with `DATE2: 26Jun2019 11:42:40` (note the time is my local time for some reason).

Comment: I suspect a silly error is somewhere: regardless of my input date it is always giving 26Jun2019 and local time.

Comment: `date: invalid date` is not a bash error at all. `date` is not part of bash; it's a separate command typically provided by your OS vendor -- so you could get that error in code that *didn't even invoke a shell*, if it uses the `excve()` syscall to invoke `date` directly.

Comment: (If it accepts `--date=now`, you presumably have the GNU version of date -- which would make sense, for a mingw-based distribution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert timestamp to a date then you have to use `@`:

```
date --date=@1561344591 '+%F %T'
2019-06-24 04:49:51
```

The reason why you got seemingly correct result even with the error message is because your `DATE1` is now, so your inner `date` call produces an error and returns nothing and then the outer call is just `--date=+2 days`, which produces 2 days from now.

I don't think you can use date-time in timestamp format together with relative statements, it doesn't work even with `@`. You have to convert your timestamp to human readable date first but even then you have to be careful. You could think that this is enough:

```
date --date="$(date --date=@1561344591 "+%F %T") + 2 days" "+%F %T"
2019-06-25 04:49:51
```

As you can see it is still wrong and that's because `+2` is parsed as a timezone. You fix it by explicitly including timezone in you conversion from timestamp:

```
date --date="$(date --date=@1561344591 "+%F %T%Z") + 2 days" "+%F %T"
2019-06-26 04:49:51
```

In general, using bash debugging `set -x` and date debugging `date --debug ...` helps with solving such problems.